# doing away with loop result in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datagrid

I am working on a kind of order where I have multiple amount in different currencies in just one attribute. So am trying to make `sum` on different currencies inside that attribute using other attributes in the table, which works fine but outputs the result as a count of all the rows instead of just showing the sum of the random values calculated.

**orders_controller.rb**

```
module Admin
  module Statistic
    class OrdersController < BaseController
      def show
        @orders_grid = ::Statistic::OrdersGrid.new(params[:statistic_orders_grid]) do |value|
          value.page(params[:page]).per(20)
        end
        @assets = @orders_grid.assets


        #@fee_groups = {:fee => @assets.sum(:fee)}
        @fee_groups = {
          :fee => @assets.sum{|t|
            olaoa = t.type
            market_string = t.currency
            base_currency = market_string.slice(0..2)
            quote_currency = market_string.slice(3..5)
            if olaoa == 'OrderBid' and base_currency == 'btc'
              "#{ t.fee.to_s + ' ' + base_currency.upcase }"
            elsif olaoa == 'OrderAsk' and quote_currency == 'ngn'
              "#{ t.fee.to_s + ' ' + quote_currency.upcase }"
            end
          }
        }

        @orders_filter = true
        @orders_group = true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**summary.htm.slim**

```
.panel.panel-default
  .panel-heading
    h4.panel-title.row
      a data-parent="#filter-accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#summary"
        span.col-xs-8.text-muted = t('admin.statistic.summary')
        span.col-xs-4.text-right.text-muted = t('admin.statistic.click-to-expand')
  #summary.panel-collapse.collapse
    .panel-body
      .datagrid-groups
        - if !@orders_group
          - if groups
            - groups.each do |key, val|
              .datagrid.group.row
                span.col-xs-2.title = t("admin.statistic.#{controller_name}.#{controller.action_name}.#{key}")
                span.col-xs-10.value = val
        - if @orders_group
          / Summary Count Loop
          - if groups
            - groups.each do |key, val|
              .datagrid.group.row
                span.col-xs-2.title = t("admin.statistic.#{controller_name}.#{controller.action_name}.#{key}")
                span.col-xs-10.value = pluralize(val, 'Order')
          / Summary Fees Loop. This is the Fee loop causing problem if am rigth and I dont know how to fix this.
          - if @fee_groups
            - @fee_groups.each do |key, val|
              .datagrid.group.row
                span.col-xs-2.title = t("admin.statistic.#{controller_name}.#{controller.action_name}.#{key}")
                span.col-xs-10.value = val
```

**The result of the code**

[image: Result Image]

So as you can see it renders 0.0BTC 5 times because the filter only has 5 orders. How do i deal with this. I want just the sum of all BTCs to show in the result instead of showing it 5 times.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unindent the whole block with `- if @fee_groups`.

Comment: Even with that it wont work.

Comment: Can you give more insight ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you sum strings in you're @fee_groups query that will results in putting strings next to each other instead of a total amount.

If you call it like this

```
@fee_groups = { fee: @assets.sum{|t| t.fee}}
```

You will get the total sum of you're assets.